# refresh page after updated model - Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, refresh

I want to refresh current page after any user update

I'm trying to do something like that in User Model :

```
 public static function boot()
    {
        self::updated(function ($model) {
            return back(); //or redirect(Request::url())

        });
    }
```

but it wasn't working.
How can I refresh the page if any user updated

Comment: `return redirect()->back()` should work. But if you do it like this, you are taking for granted that the request has been done in the `/models/{id}/edit` view.

Comment: it's not work. it work only in controller but I need to use it in Model

Comment: The `User` model is not the right place to perform logic like this. Logic related to HTTP requests should remain within the realms of your middleware and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the model event functions `creating`/`created`/`updating`/`updating`/`saved`/`saving` should only ever return `false` or nothing (void). Returning false in for instance `updating` (that is: before the model is persisted in the database) cancels the model update (this works for all propagating events, see https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events#stopping-the-propagation-of-an-event).

To "refresh" the current page after a user update, you have to be more specific about what you require. The `back()` function that you use (or the aliases `redirect()->back()` or even `app('redirect')->back())` is (to my knowledge) to be used **in controllers** and it uses the `Referer` header or a property in the user's session to determine to which page to send the client to. This is most often used with validation errors, so that you can send the user back to the page they came from along with any possible validation error messages.

Using `back()` (or any other request completions like `return response()->json('mydata')`) inside events is wrong and it doesn't even work since the result of such events is not being used to complete the request. The only valid thing you "could" do is to try *validation* inside an event, which in turn could throw `ValidationException`s and is therefore automatically handled.

What you should do is use the controller method that actually handles the request that updates the user:

```php
// UserController.php
/** (PUT) Update a user */
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    if($user->update($this->validate($request, [/* validations */])) {
        return redirect()->back();
        // or even be explicit and use `return redirect()->route('users.show', $user);`
    }
    // `update()` returned false, meaning one of the model events returned `false`
    // (there is no exception thrown here).
    session()->flash('alert-info', 'Something went wrong');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```